# Solving polynomial equation modulo $p^n$

Tags: number-theory

I have to solve the equation
$$ X^4 - 3 X^2 + 27 \equiv 0 \bmod 5^k$$
for the first few $k = 1, \ldots, 6$

I don't even know how to start, ok, for $k=1$ 
$$ X^4 - 3 X^2 + 27 \equiv 0 \bmod 5\, ,$$
I can guess an answer, like $X \equiv 4 \bmod{5}$, but how should I proceed for higher powers?

Edit: This exercise is to motivate the Hensel's Lemma, so no, I'm not allowed to use Hensel's Lemma.

Comment: [Hensel's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma)?

Comment: for $k=2,$ take $X = 4 + 5 w,$ where we can require $0 \leq w \leq 4$ Could also use $X = 1 + 4 w$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=x^4-3x^2+27$$

First the equation $f(x)=0\mod 5$ have the two solutions $a_0=1, b_0=4$

Let us assume that the equation $f(x)=0\mod 5^n$ have two solutions $a_n$ and $b_n$, so if we want to solve the equation:
$$f(x)=0 \mod 5^{n+1} $$
so any solution of this equation will be of the form $x=a_n+k5^n$ or $x=b_n+k5^n$, because of the symmetry let $x=a+k5^n$ so :
$$ f(a+k5^n)=f(a)+k5^n f'(a)\mod 5^{n+1}$$
This is equivalent to $\frac{f(a)}{5^n}+kf'(a)=0 \mod 5$ and because $gcd(f(x), f'(x))=1$ we conclude that $f'(a)\neq 0\mod 5$ finally :
$$k=\frac{f(a)}{5^nf'(a)}\mod 5$$

This gives the following definitions:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a_0=1 & a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{f(a_n)}{f'(a_n)}\\ 
b_0=1 & b_{n+1}=b_n+\frac{f(b_n)}{f'(b_n)}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: It is $f{\color{red}'}(a)$ that is $\neq 0$.  Also you obtain a congruence $\bmod 5^{2n}$, which may speed up computations.

Comment: How do you get $f(a + k5^n) = f(a) + k5^n f'(a) \pmod {5^{n+1}}$